# How do I restrict upload size?

Tags: php, html

Hello I am developing an upload system for uploading images. I have some restrictions in place such as only allowing certain types of image depending on the extension (jpg, jpeg, png ...).

That part of the validation works just fine. I tested by uploading a pdf file and got the error i was expecting and the file was not uploaded. I also have an if statement to make sure the file size is less than 200KB. This however, does not work. Images of 2MB are also getting uploaded even though they are too big. The idea is to upload 5 images.

Here is the relevant php code:

include_once 'db.inc.php';

```
for($int = 1; $int <= 5; $int++){
    $str = (string) $int;
    $inputName = 'image' . $int;

    if(isset($_FILES[$inputName]['name'])){
        $name = $_FILES[$inputName]['name'];
        $size = $_FILES[$inputName]['size'];
        $type = $_FILES[$inputName]['type'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES[$inputName]['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES[$inputName]['error'];
        $dest = 'uploads/';
        echo $size;
        echo $name;

        if(!empty($name)){
            global $dest;
            global $tmp_name;
            global $size;
            global $name;

            $jpg = 'image/jpg';
            $jpeg = 'image/jpeg';
            $pjpeg = 'image/pjpeg';
            $x_png = 'image/x-png';
            $png = 'image/png';
            $gif = 'image/gif';
            $bmp = 'image/bmp';

            $allowedExts = array('jpg','jpeg','png','bmp');
            $temp = explode('.',$name);
            $ext = end($temp);

            if($_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $jpg 
            or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $jpeg or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $pjpeg 
            or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $x_png or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $png
            or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $png or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $gif
            or $_FILES[$inputName]['type'] == $bmp)
            {
                if(!$size < 200000){
                    echo '<p>' . $name . 'Is too big' . '</p>';
                    if(!in_array($ext, $allowedExts)){
                        echo '<p>' . $name . 'Is not an image' . '</p>'
                    }
                }else{
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest.$name);
                }
            }

            else{
                global $name;
                echo '<div><p style="background:black;color:red;font-size:14px;position:relative;top:5px;left:30px"><span>' . $name . ' is either too big or not an image' . '</span></p></div>';
            }
        }
    }
    $int = (int) $str;
}
```

So that was the php, here is the relevant html also for reference:

```
                            "<div class="fieldRow"><label class="image1" for="image 1" style="display:block;width:100%;">Image 1: <input class="pickImage" name="image1" type="file" /><?php ;?></label></div>
                            <div class="fieldRow"><label class="image2" for="image 2" style="display:block;width:100%;">Image 2: <input class="pickImage" name="image2" type="file" /><?php ;?></label></div>
                            <div class="fieldRow"><label class="image3" for="image 3" style="display:block;width:100%;">Image 3: <input class="pickImage" name="image3" type="file" /><?php ;?></label></div>
                            <div class="fieldRow"><label class="image4" for="image 4" style="display:block;width:100%;">Image 4: <input class="pickImage" name="image4" type="file" /><?php ;?></label></div>
                            <div class="fieldRow"><label class="image5" for="image 5" style="display:block;width:100%;">Image 5: <input class="pickImage" name="image5" type="file" /><?php ;?></label></div>"
```

The entire form is much larger than that and has the appropriate enc_type attributes along with a method of post and the action attribute which has the value of the php file's name. If you could point me in the right direction that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What is this for? `global $size` It seems to be overwriting what was in `$size` previously.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
```

To your HTML form and then in PHP you check it:

```
// Error Checking Extended
    if($_FILES['image1']['error'] == 2) { // Change to your file field
    echo "You've exceeded the maximum file upload size of 512kb.";
    return false;
    }
```

EDIT:

I leave it up to you for how you want to work with the data, if it is easier to do each separate file than duplicate it, but for re-factoring and clean code I would suggest that you loop over this from a $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "20M");
```